# Build Swift for iOS and visionOS on both Xcode 14 and 15 without warnings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode15, visionos

We'd like to find a way to write iOS-only Swift code blocks in code that supports multiple Apple platforms and runs without warnings on both Xcode 14 and 15.

It's complicated by the fact that `#if os(iOS)` evaluates to true for `visionOS` so the test `#if os(iOS) && !os(visionOS)` is needed to build iOS-only code on Xcode 15. However, this generates a warning on Xcode 14 since `visionOS` is not recognized.

`#if os(iOS) && (swift(<5.9) || !os(visionOS))` also generates warnings on Xcode 14.

We've found that the following runs warning free on both:

```
    #if swift(>=5.9)
      #if os(iOS) && !os(visionOS)
        code block
      #endif
    #else 
      #if os(iOS)
        code block
      #endif
    #endif
```

But this is ugly since the code block needs to be duplicated. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Under Xcode 14.3 and Xcode 15, the following will allow you to compile without any warnings:

```swift
#if swift(>=5.9) && os(visionOS)
    // visionOS code, if any, under Xcode 15
#elseif os(iOS)
    // iOS code under Xcode 14/15
#endif
```

Of course you can add other `#elseif os(xxx)` as needed (for example, macOS).

Under Xcode 14.2 you will get a warning about the unknown `visionOS` but the code will otherwise build correctly without any code duplication.

Comment: That would be nice, but Xcode 14.2 warns with "Unknown operating system for build configuration 'os'"

Comment: I don't get that warning with Xcode 14.3. Can you update to Xcode 14.3 from 14.2? Or are you somehow using Swift 5.9 with Xcode 14.2?

Comment: This is for SDK code that we want to support back to 14.1. And yes, it looks like Swift 5.8 doesn't short-circuit evaluating the operands of the `&&` operation

Comment: But Xcode 14.3 uses Swift 5.8 and I don't have any warnings using the code posted in my answer. Curious what the benefit of supporting Xcode 14.1 versus 14.3 is. I certainly understand Xcode 14 vs 15 but not 14.1 vs 14.3. Anyone running Xcode 14.1 should have no reason to avoid upgrading Xcode 14.3 (other than the large download).

Comment: As an SDK vendor, we prefer to avoid being the reason developers must change their Xcode version. Xcode 14.3 is especially significant because it also requires a macOS upgrade to Ventura.

Comment: I forgot about the need for macOS 13 for Xcode 14.3.

Comment: DeviceKit has a similar need for the check to not generate warnings particularly since Swift Playgrounds has not yet been updated to support iOS 17 and Swift 5.9 so upgrading isn't even an option.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Add a version-specific package manifest that defines a build condition when building for visionOS.

Full details:

I haven't tested this, so I'm not 100% sure it will work. Also, Xcode 15.0 and Xcode 15.1 did not ship with a visionOS SDK but did ship with Swift 5.9, so that also might cause problems. Am I willing to download Xcode 14.3, Xcode 15.0, and Xcode 15.1 to test this solution? No, but I encourage you to do so.  Anyway…

You say you're an SDK vendor, so I assume you're distributing a Swift Package Manager (SwiftPM) package.

SwiftPM supports [“Version-specific Manifest Selection”](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md#version-specific-manifest-selection). You can create **two** package manifests: one named `Package.swift` and another named `Package@swift-5.9.swift`. A build system that supports Swift 5.9 or later uses the `Package@swift-5.9.swift` manifest, and a build system that doesn't support Swift 5.9 uses `Package.swift`.

Xcode 15.0 supports Swift 5.9, and earlier Xcodes do not. So Xcode 14 will use `Package.swift`, and Xcode 15 (and eventually Xcode 16, etc.) will use `Package@swift-5.9.swift`.

Create `Package@swift-5.9.swift` as a copy of `Package.swift`. Update the `swift-tools-version` line at the top of `Package@swift-5.9.swift` to version 5.9. Then (still in `Package@swift-5.9.swift`) add a `swiftSetting` to your target as follows:

```
.target(
    name: "PaulSDK",
    swiftSettings: [
        .define("supportsVisionOS", .when(platforms: [.visionOS])),
    ]
),
```

Then, in your code, check whether you're building for visionOS by checking the build condition:

```
#if supportsVisionOS
print("heyo it's visionOS")
#else
print("great sadness")
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I follow. I'm not sure how the `supportsVisionOS` flag is different from the `swift(>=5.9)` test in my question.  The question is about how to build iOS specific code that shouldn't run on visionOS without duplicating it. Anyway this will become moot in two months when AppStore drops support for Xcode 14.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your question. But now I've tested and in Xcode 15.2, `os(iOS)` is false when I build for visionOS native (not “Designed for iPad”), so I can't reproduce your problem.